# Will I lose muscle memory for a sport if I've been injured for a few months?

Tags: football, training

I play football(soccer) and I've gotten a knee injury for about 4 months now and I should be fully fit by the end of the year. Will I get significantly worse when I return or will the muscle memory for the skills acquired in my training still be at the same level as it was before injury?

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, you can retain muscle memory for years without ever using the skill involved, and carry on without any functional loss. However an injury may change the muscle and bone movements, so changing the effective outcome of the (unconscious) skill.

Answer (score 3):

I think it really depends on how long you've been playing football since before the injury. Say if you have been playing for a good 6-7 years, then you should bounce back to normal in no time. You may may face issues with stamina and getting back into shape initially, but your muscle memory should stay intact. If you've started playing recently enough for a good chunk of muscle memory to be relatively new, then you may feel that you aren't able to access the same set of skills and techniques.  However with a good recovery routine and practice with growing intensity as time progresses, you should be able to get back on the pitch in no time! Hope this helps.